# How should I ask compensation for destroyed luggage, which was primarily used to carry company equipment?

Tags: travel

I've got some pieces of luggage that I've used for frequent business travel. The luggage was primarily used to carry company equipment, including a 12 lb power supply. My personal belongings, such as change of clothes and toothpaste, was also thrown in there alongside the company equipment.

Over the course of several trips, the wheels have been worn and eventually busted off, making the luggage hard to transport, cracked nearly unusable without duct tape.  This is most painful traveling to Burbank with a good quarter mile walk to the rental car area.

Is seems reasonable that I should be able to get new luggage at company expense.  Perhaps I could amortize this over several trips. Is it common to ask for such reimbursement and how should I ask for it?

Comment: That's something you'll need to take up with your company. But let's be realistic. They're almost certainly not going to do that anymore than they would pay for worn shoes or dry cleaning for wrinkled suits.

Comment: Dry cleaning and shoes are things I would incur on my own whether I was traveling or not.  I'm going to travel again soon and need several hundred dollars of new luggage.  I don't think this is an equivalent comparison.

Comment: Will you leave the suitcases at the office so someone else can use them? Are you going to use them privately as well? I think it is the same as clothes / shoes / a bike / other items you would use for business and privately.

Comment: The comments are stacking up to a prevailing opinion that I have to eat the cost of this on my own.  Oh well.  The bottom line is that my personal property was destroyed in the course of business travel and further business travel is going to require me to buy more.

Comment: If the luggage is used to transport company property - equipment, tools, documentation, training manuals - then you could make a reasonable argument that the company should be providing carrying cases for those.

Comment: It is used for all of those things, sometimes including a 12 lb power supply.  They are all thrown in there alongside my change of undergarments and toothpaste.  Wow, the down-votes keep coming.  Is this question really this bad?

Comment: Really the only reason for you to have luggage is for business?    Wearing out wheels is not different than wearing out shoes.  And it does cost several hundred dollars for a nice roller.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with the shoe comparison, except that I'd estimate >90% Business use for these pieces.  I usually travel much lighter and less frequently for my personal travel, rarely using this luggage.  Perhaps the travel habits of the prevailing comments is heavier on personal use.  I do use my shoes for personal reasons more frequently.

Comment: Professions that require a lot of travel typically pay more due to the travel requirements.  This is one of the reasons why.

Comment: And 90% of my use of my business shoes is business.  90% of my use of  business casual clothes is business.  90% of my use of my commute backpack is is business.

Comment: Clothes, shoes and commute I presume are items that are part of your day to day work.  I'm talking about a personal expense incurred due to repeated travel assignments.  Some companies give a cash per-diem for personal expenses.  My company works with actual expenses, usually with receipts and a mileage log.

Comment: it appears that travel assignments are your day-to-day work

Comment: I suspect people are negatively reacting to the situation out of reflex, but part of the equation involves carrying a 12 lb power supply, among other equipment.   If the weight of the company material is causing damage to normal travel suitcases, then the company needs to look into a better container to provide you, not wear out your suitcases.

Comment: Are you paid for meals that you would otherwise have to pay yourself? How about mileage you would otherwise yourself?  Mileage typically exceeds actual cost.  How is car mileage pertinent for going to the car rental.  You are making it up as you go.

Comment: @2NinerRomeo I have edited your question to hopefully make it more on-topic and acceptable here. In particular, I have incorporated your comment about the luggage being used for carrying company equipment into the description. If this differs significantly from your intention, please revert my edit or post a comment for me to do it.

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes and being closed for, this is a common enough issue with an equally common solution

Comment: @Kilisi The early close votes were because it appeared the question was asking compensation for a personal luggage that wore out on a business trip. The point about the luggage being used to carry company equipment was added in later from OP's comments. As your answer clearly shows, this is not a company-specific problem at all. Moreover, the edit changed the question from "should company compensate me?" to "how should I ask?", which should be on-topic. We have allowed similar or worse questions here, not sure why the close votes still keep pouring in. FWIW, I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: FYI: it's common for wheels to fail on luggage and they should be easily replaceable. If you routinely carry this kind of weight you'll want to include the cost of regular replacements in your discussion on putting this on expenses.

Answer (score 10):

Don't ask for compensation, that is a bit unrealistic.

However it's totally fine to ask for a bag to carry work stuff in. For instance I supply my guys with tool belts and backpacks. Most bigger tools have their own bags etc,. If I give a laptop, it goes with either a heavy duty carry case or a bag.

These aren't personal items, these remain with the equipment at all times, they're work gear. I'll deduct it from their pay if they lose it, but I'll replace them when they're worn out.